Implementing Firebase Security Rules to Allow Only Admin and Regular Users to Read and Write, While Keeping Sign-Up/Sign-In Functional
I need to establish Firebase security rules to allow only admin user types and regular users (for every user created in Firebase Authentication, a user document is written in Cloud Firestore where the user type is defined) to read and write. However, I still want to allow sign-up and sign-in pages to read and write, as sign-up pages create the user document and sign-in reads the user document to determine which page to take the user to. However, I am concerned that someone could potentially exploit these pages to perform excessive reads and writes. I am using react and nextjs.
What I know is to utilize Google Cloud API key rules to restrict my Firebase API key to only accept reads and writes from my website exclusively. However, through inspection tools, someone could potentially initiate a series of writes in my sign-up process.

It's not possible to do what you're explaining here.  A Firebase API key is essentially public information by design, and you can't stop people from getting that value after you publish your app.  You need to focus your attention back on to security rules to enforce that certain individuals can read or write the specific data that you want.  Security rules have nothing to do with API keys.

If you are having problems getting your security rules to work, you should post a new question explaining what you're trying to do along with the rules and app code that aren't working the way you expect.  If security rules are not sufficient, you must instead send all client access through a backend API that checks that the user can do what their API call is requesting.
